# Ajax call php function breaks all javascript functions and page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm trying to validate if a username is already taking or not. This onchange of an input field. I already got other checks but they don't work anymore since I added the ajax call. I'm new to ajax and javascript so the error can be there.

the html form:

```html
<form action="test" method="post">
  <input id="username" type="text" placeholder="Gebruikersnaam" name="username" required onchange="checkUserName()">
  <br>
  <input id="email" type="text" placeholder="Email" name="email" required onchange="validateEmail()">
  <br>
  <input id="pass1" type="password" placeholder="Type wachtwoord" name="password1" required>
  <br>
  <input id="pass2" type="password" placeholder="Bevestig wachtwoord" name="password2" required onchange="passwordCheck()">
  <br>
  <select name="typeAccount">
    <option value="bedrijf">Bedrijf</option>
    <option value="recruiter">Recruiter</option>
    <option value="werkzoekende">Talent zoekt job</option>
  </select>
  <p id="demo1">
  </P>
  <p id="demo2">
  </P>
  <button type="submit">Scrijf mij in!</button>
</form>
```

the javascript that I use:

```
    <script src="jquery.js">
        function passwordCheck(){
            var password1 = document.getElementById('pass1').value;
            var password2 = document.getElementById('pass2').value;

            if(password1 !== password2){
                document.getElementById("pass1").style.borderColor = "#ff3333";
                document.getElementById("pass2").style.borderColor = "#ff3333";
            }else{
                document.getElementById("pass1").style.borderColor = "#1aff1a";
                document.getElementById("pass2").style.borderColor = "#1aff1a";
            }
        }
        function validate(email){
            var re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
            return re.test(email);
        }
        function validateEmail(){
            var email = document.getElementById('email').value;
            if(validate(email)){
                document.getElementById("email").style.borderColor = "#1aff1a";
            }else{
                document.getElementById("email").style.borderColor = "#ff3333";
            }
        }
        function checkUserName(){
            var username = document.getElementById('username').value;
            if(username === ""){
                document.getElementById("username").style.borderColor = "#ff3333";
            }else{
                $.ajax({
                    url: "userCheck.php",
                    data: { action : username },
                    succes: function(result){
                        if(result === 1){
                            document.getElementById("username").style.borderColor = "#1aff1a";
                        }else{
                            document.getElementById("username").style.borderColor = "#ff3333";
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    </script>
```

The php script I use this is in a different file:

```
<?php
    include("connect.php");
    $connect = new Connect();
    $username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']); 
    $result = mysql_query('select username from usermaindata where username = "'. $username .'"'); 
    if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0){  
        echo 0;  
    }else{  
        echo 1;  
    }  
?>
```

The script and the html form is in the same html-file and the php is in a seperate PHP-file. 
I just want to check if the name is already in the database or not.

Comment: mysql_* functions warnings are comming... What your browser's console says?

Comment: What does it means - `not work anymore`?

Comment: please check your browser console for errors..

Comment: if you would put a different second password or a bad email these would be red

Comment: Can you try this:

<script src="jquery.js"></script>

<script>
...Your functions here
</script>

Comment: What is the exact error you're getting? Look to console tab in the browser's developer tools

Comment: I get the error  Uncaught ReferenceError: checkUserName is not definedonchange @ register.html:66. And this I get when I execute every function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume your database connection is perfect.

`$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);`

change above code to

`$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_connection,$_REQUEST['action']);`

because in your ajax you're doing like

```
$.ajax({
                    url: "userCheck.php",
                    data: { action : username },
                    succes: function(result){
                        if(result === 1){
                            document.getElementById("username").style.borderColor = "#1aff1a";
                        }else{
                            document.getElementById("username").style.borderColor = "#ff3333";
                        }
                    }
                });
```

You have not specified request type and you're fetching value using `$_POST` with different variable name `username` which is actually value
You should use `$_REQUEST['action']`
And make sure you've added `jquery.js` file in your html.

Comment: @jaro1989 No problem. :)

Comment: I checked the chrome console and I get the following error: Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Comment: have you added `jquery.min.js` file ?

Comment: Yes I added this to the project folder and renamed it to jquery.js

Comment: `<script src="jquery.js">` do this `<script src="jquery.js"></script>`
write this before your javascript
`<script type="text/javascript">`

Comment: That did the trick. Also I wasen't checking on a local webserver so after setting this up it worked perfect